# How to create an application for windows explorer contextual menu?

Tags: windows

I do not know how exactly this procedure is called but I want to create an application that lives only on the contextual menu of Windows Explorer (left click on explorer), something like http://www.extrabit.com/copyfilenames/ but I want to create another type of application. Where do I start? I am familiar with C++, C#, Visual Studio...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking is called Shell Extensions, for more info check these MSDN entries about this topic.

- [`Working with Shell Extensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Creating Shell Extensions with Shell Instance Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997573.aspx)
- [Creating Shell Extension Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Registering Shell Extension Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144110%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Walkthrough: Creating a Shell Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh290138.aspx)